# How can I loop within a jQuery case statement?

Tags: jquery, loops, case

I am trying to do something like this

```
case KEY.ATSIGN:
    while(!KEY.SPACE) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(onChange, options.delayLong);
    }
    break;
```

ATSIGN = 50 which is the ascii code for the @.. This invokes the autocomplete dropdown.

SPACE = 32 which is the ascii for the space character.

I need it to dropdown the autocomplete AND allow subset searching or matchContains searching up until a space character is entered. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
[Facebook like Autosuggestion with jQuery, Ajax and PHP.](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/autosuggestion-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html)

Answer (score 1):

is your code like this?

```
switch(e.which){
  case KEY.ATSIGN : while(!KEY.SPACE){...}
}
```

if it is, then its wrong. when ever keypressed happen its like while(true).

try this

```
switch(e.which){
  case KEY.SPACE: onChange();
}
```

i'm not quite understand. but try this.

```
<input type='text' /><select>...</select>
...
$("input").keydown(function(e){
  switch(e.which){
    case KEY.ATSIGN : $(this).keyup(doSomething);
    case KEY.SPACE : $(this).unbind("keyup");
  }
})
function doSomething(){...}
```

Comment: Thanks Bonshington... The problem with that is that it doesn't invoke the dropdown at first when you type an @ sign.... I need it to engage the dropdown when the @ is typed and then the autosuggest should work normally and then in essence, when the SPACE is entered, it should disengage the dropdown and wait for the next @ sign to be typed....